# Short story where the protagonist’s brain has a switch between two selves

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a short story where the protagonist’s brain has a switch between two selves, identical.  He flips the switch a few times and notices no difference. Until near the end of the story when he flips it and loses control to the other self, who he’s been suppressing without knowing.  And who has by then significantly diverged from his original self.

I think I read this around 1980-1983. It was probably published in the '70s. And quite likely by a big name writer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: Thanks for following up. I think i read it around 1980-1983.  Was probably published in the 70s.  And quite likely by a big name writer.

Comment: This sounds like Greg Egan's short story "Learning To Be Me", from his 1995 collection [_Axiomatic_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiomatic_(book)), but the timing doesn't line up.

Comment: Milo, thanks.  Yes for sure the timing is off.  I was a teenager in the 80s for sure.  However now I know to check out Egan, thanks.

Comment: In case it helps the timing, I was sure this was Donovan’s Brain by Siodmak.  But upon reading the synopsis, it doesn’t fit.  The book was from my father’s pulp sci fi paperbacks.  All very thin. And quick reading.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This may be an essay by Daniel Dennett, called "Where Am I", discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/g/rec.arts.sf.written/c/Ic6gvdJAq60), and collected in **The Mind's I** (1981): it is quite similar to Egan's Learning to Be Me.

> Spoilers for both works follow.
>
> Both stories imagine that you could produce a "backup" of someone's
> brain by having a computer model of the brain receiving all the same
> sensory input so that the backup thinks it is the person and thinks
> the body is responding to the backup's commands, and that you could
> switch from one to another without the brain, the backup, or any
> observer being able to tell any difference.
>
> Both stories recognize that if there were an instant's difference
> between the backup's thoughts and the brain's thoughts, the illusion
> that the backup was controling the body would be shattered and that
> the two would irrevocably diverge into different minds from that
> point. Both stories have that happen and the backup finds itself a
> trapped observer in a body the brain is controling. Both stories cast
> doubt on whether the narrator is the brain or the backup and both end
> with the tables being turned.

The whole essay is [here](https://www.lehigh.edu/%7Emhb0/Dennett-WhereAmI.pdf).

Quote from near the end:

> In any case, every time I’ve flipped the switch so far, nothing has
> happened. So let’s give it a try … “THANK GOD! I THOUGHT YOU’D NEVER
> FLIP THAT SWITCH! You can’t imagine how horrible it’s been these last
> two weeks—but now you know; it’s your turn in purgatory. How I’ve
> longed for this moment! You see, about two weeks ago—excuse me, ladies
> and gentlemen, but I’ve got to explain this to my … um, brother, I
> guess you could say, but he’s just told you the facts, so you’ll
> understand—about two weeks ago our two brains drifted just a bit out
> of synch. I don’t know whether my brain is now Hubert or Yorick, any
> more than you do, but in any case, the two brains drifted apart, and
> of course once the process started, it snowballed, for I was in a
> slightly different receptive state for the input we both received, a
> difference that was soon magnified. In no time at all the illusion
> that I was in control of my body—our body—was completely dissipated.
> There was nothing I could do—no way to call you.

Comment: Yes that’s it, well done.  I clicked a green checkmark next to Andrew’s answer.  Am I supposed to do something to close the question?

Comment: You don't need to do anything else. Glad I was able to help

Comment: @CorwinMacleod Closing a question is a specific cleanup process on this site and it's usually done for questions that are low quality, duplicates of others, etc. Your question is a good one, so we wouldn't want to close it :)

Comment: Wow thanks, I thought it was terrible and i’d face a dozen let me google that for you comments.

Comment: A grammatical question with specific details and an estimate of when it was read makes this a very good one.  Come back with more!

Answer (score 1):

As someone has already answered, my first thought here was Daniel Dennett, but not actually the story itself. There's a quasi-documentary film called *Victim of the Brain* from 1988 that explores the ideas of Dennett and Douglas Hofstadter (I learned about this when I studied cognitive science at Indiana University, where Hofstadter is an emeritus prof). In this film (my best guess is at [this time point](https://youtu.be/_F_4BeK4EjY?t=2129), though he actually flips the switch at 55:00) Dennett actually acts out this story himself, complete with an actual brain-in-a-vat. It's pretty campy but I love it so much.