# Show about scientist whose body can be switched between control by his brain or a machine

Tags: story-identification, tv

A scientist has a machine that simulates his brain and it is calibrated perfectly. He has a switch around his waist that can switch from controlling his body by his brains to by this machine. And though it shouldn't matter who is controlling the body, because they do exactly the same things and have the same thoughts, they both (brain and machine) yearn for the fact of knowing they are in control and not the other. And all that they have to know who is in control, is the knowledge of the position of the switch.

In an interview with a science journalist, where the scientist keeps insisting that it doesn't matter who is in control, as they both always have the same thoughts, the interviewer keeps taunting the him to turn the switch and let the other take control.

The subject keeps being very reluctant to turn the switch, but eventually does so, because the interviewer persuaded him. And then the scientist directly becomes overwhelmed with joy and gloats about finally being in charge of the body again.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you see this?  Since you describe it as a "show" I tagged it [tag:tv] but if it's a web series or something else we can retag it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was on tv. But it could have been like 20 years back or so. Not sure if it was a series, movie or a short. Maybe even Outer Limits or Twilight Zone

Comment: I don't recognize it as an OL episode, but I could have forgotten some.

Comment: This sounds **extremely** similar to Greg Egan's short story *Learning to be me*, collected in *Axiomatic*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This appears to be a duplicate of this question [Short story where the protagonist’s brain has a switch between two selves](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/275284/short-story-where-the-protagonist-s-brain-has-a-switch-between-two-selves/)

The answer is Daniel Dennett's "Where Am I?" which is available [here](https://www.lehigh.edu/%7Emhb0/Dennett-WhereAmI.pdf).

Relevant quote

> In any case, every time I’ve flipped the switch so far, nothing has
> happened. So let’s give it a try … “THANK GOD! I THOUGHT YOU’D NEVER
> FLIP THAT SWITCH! You can’t imagine how horrible it’s been these last
> two weeks—but now you know; it’s your turn in purgatory. How I’ve
> longed for this moment! You see, about two weeks ago—excuse me, ladies
> and gentlemen, but I’ve got to explain this to my … um, brother, I
> guess you could say, but he’s just told you the facts, so you’ll
> understand—about two weeks ago our two brains drifted just a bit out
> of synch. I don’t know whether my brain is now Hubert or Yorick, any
> more than you do, but in any case, the two brains drifted apart, and
> of course once the process started, it snowballed, for I was in a
> slightly different receptive state for the input we both received, a
> difference that was soon magnified. In no time at all the illusion
> that I was in control of my body—our body—was completely dissipated.
> There was nothing I could do—no way to call you.

Note that the other version is compassionate, not gloating - but otherwise the scenario is identical

Comment: You are right. It is it. But I've seen this so long ago, that the part where "THANK GOD! I THOUGHT YOU’D NEVER FLIP THAT SWITCH!" was what I remembered most, and I took it as gloating. But now that I see it again, that is a false memory.